# Limit to 2 decimal places for a number like (25) with angular percentage pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I want to convert number to percentage format like 25 to 25.00% with angular percentage pipe.I have used this one.

```
{{ number | percent : '0.2-2'}}
```

I am getting like this 2,500.00%.any one can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're using it with a big number, check this example on stackblitz. Remember that `1` equals `100%`, so to show `25%`, you need to put `0.25`

Also, check the docs and their examples, should be doubtless

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iszurj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide the number by 100 to get the desired output.

Input:

```
const number = 25;

{{ number/100 | percent : '0.2'}}
```

Output:

25.00%